# Обновление геопозиции при свернутом приложении в Android O и Android Lollipop

Tags: java, android, геолокация

Есть сервис который получает обновления геолокации. Щас сервис работает через привязку, т.е.  я вызываю `Context.bindService()` в `onCreate()` и `Context.unbindService()` в `onDestroy()` , но при блокировке экрана, обновления прекращают поступать.

Меня интересует есть ли возможность получать апдейты геолокации при заблокированом экране, которое подходит для `Api level 21 - 26`.

```
/**
 * Created by Kirill Stoianov on 09.11.17.
 */

public class LocationService
        extends Service
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    public static final String TAG = LocationService.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * Code for request settings.
     */
    public static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 1023;

    /**
     * Interval for receive location updates.
     */
    private final static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;


    /**
     * Google API client. 
     */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * Location manager
     */
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

    /**
     * Location request to Google Api.
     */
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;


    /**
     * Callback which must be registered in activity for receive location
     * settings request.
     */
    private ActivityLocationSettingsCallback mActivitySettingsCallback;

    /**
     * List with location listeners. Used from outside of this service
     * from {@link android.app.Activity} of {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment}
     */
    private ArrayList<OnLocationUpdateListener> mLocationListeners;

    /**
     * Current binder for this service.
     */
    private LocalBinder binder = new LocalBinder();

    /**
     * Server api interface.
     */
    public GeoPositionApi api = Application.getAppComponent().getGeoPositionApi();


    /**
     * Service binder, for get access to inner service methods.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public LocationService getService() {
            return LocationService.this;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Location request callback.
     * It called when {@link #mFusedLocationClient} receive {@link LocationResult}.
     */
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {

            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {


                //send new location to server here

                //notify listener
                LocationService.this.mLocationListeners.forEach(listener -> listener.onLocationUpdate(location));

                //get device user id
                String deviceUserId = Application.getAppComponent().getAppPrefs().getDeviceUserId();

                //if device user id is null -  don't make api call
                if (deviceUserId == null) return;

                //prepare data
                UserGeoPosition position = new UserGeoPosition(deviceUserId, location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude(), location.getAltitude(), location.getTime());
                String json = GsonHelper.getWithExclusionStrategy().toJson(position);


                Log.wtf(TAG, json);
                //make api call
                api.addGeolocation(json)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
                        .subscribe(userGeoPositionResponse -> {
                            //do nothing
                        });
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public LocationService() {
    }


    /**
     * Called by the system when the service is first created.  Do not call this method directly.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        //prepare location request
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        this.mLocationListeners = new ArrayList<>();

        //Build Google Play Services
        buildGoogleApiClient();

        //Init location client
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        //Connect to Google Api
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        return this.binder;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "onUnbind() called with: intent = [" + intent + "]");

        //remove update callback
        mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this.mLocationCallback);


        //Connect to Google Api
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();


        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {


        //make setting request to be sure that geo location service if available.
        //NOTE: it must be optional, and call only if needed, tan remove this line
        //and call this method only if needed.
        makeSettingsRequest();

        //start listening location updates
        startLocationUpdates();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended: " + i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: " + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
    }

    /**
     * Initialize Google API client
     */
    private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Start listening location updates.
     * <p>
     * Called after service binding in {@link #onBind(Intent)} and after
     * {@link #mGoogleApiClient}  will connected in method {@link #onConnected(Bundle)}.
     * <p>
     * It mean than start listening location updates must be started when {@link #mGoogleApiClient}
     * has already connected.
     */
    private void startLocationUpdates() {


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            //init location update listener
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this.mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());

        } else {
            //do nothing
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Make location setting request.
     * If location settings are not satisfied than {@link #mActivitySettingsCallback} will called
     * for make request to enable Location service. Otherwise if {@link #mActivitySettingsCallback} == null
     * is settings will not be enable - {@link #mLocationRequest} will not receive location updates.
     */
    private void makeSettingsRequest() {


        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        //**************************
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient\
        //**************************

        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this).checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
        task.addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {
            try {
                LocationSettingsResponse response = task1.getResult(ApiException.class);
                // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                // requests here.

                /*
                 * Start updates.
                 */


            } catch (ApiException exception) {
                switch (exception.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the
                        // user a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Cast to a resolvable exception.
                            ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) exception;


                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            if (this.mActivitySettingsCallback != null)
                                this.mActivitySettingsCallback.onSettingsNotSatisfied(resolvable);

                        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                            // Ignore, should be an impossible error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register setting callback for main application activity.
     * Used for notify activity about location settings are not satisfied.
     *
     * @param activitySettingsCallback - callback implementation in bounded activity.
     */
    public void setActivitySettingsCallback(ActivityLocationSettingsCallback activitySettingsCallback) {
        this.mActivitySettingsCallback = activitySettingsCallback;
    }
}
```

Comment: foreground service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Они рекомендуют при сворачивании приложения стартовать `Foreground Service`. Пример: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService